# update_attribute 'undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, controller

I have two additional integer fields, `:votes_up` and `:votes_down` in my Microphoto model in Rails application. I have not set any initial values in DB manually.

This is in my controller:

```
  def vote_up
    @microphoto = Microphoto.find(params[:id])
    @microphoto.update_attribute(:votes_up, @microphoto.votes_up + 1)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def vote_down
    @microphoto = Microphoto.find(params[:id])
    @microphoto.update_attribute(:votes_down, @microphoto.votes_down + 1)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

and this is in my view:

```
<%= link_to "vote up", vote_up_microphotos_url(feed_item.id), :method => :put %> 
<%= link_to "vote down", vote_down_microphotos_url(feed_item.id), :method => :put %>
```

but, when I click on for example, vote up link, it gives me the error:

```
NoMethodError in MicrophotosController#vote_up
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

I think there should be a problem with usage of `update_attribute`. Also a friend of mine mentioned that there is chance the problem is due to the initial value of `0` not set for the fields.

**UPDATED**

Another problem, must be a typo, but I cannot find it. votes_up link works and renders correctly but votes_down not! `uninitialized constant MicrophotosController::O`

Comment: I believe your friend is probably correct.  If the field has no default value, you will be trying to add `nil + 1` which will give the error you received.   You could set the initial value in a migration or in the `new` method.

Comment: Try with this: `(@microphoto.votes_up || 0) + 1` this means if `@microphoto.votes_up` is nil (not equal to zero, no default value), it will use 0 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem here is** that your attribute `votes_up` of the instance `@microphoto` is `nil`.

There is **several ways for you to solve this**:

**#1: set a default value** for the attribute `votes_up` with a `after_create` callback:

```
class Microphoto < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :set_defaults
  #...  

  def set_defaults
    self.votes_up = 0
    self.votes_down = 0
    self.save
  end
```

**#2: Use Zero** if votes_up is `nil`:

```
nil || 10 #=> returns 10 (try it in your console!)
# in your case:
(@microphoto.votes_up || 0) + 1
# the full line:
@microphoto.update_attribute(:votes_up, (@microphoto.votes_up || 0) + 1)
```

---

**To Display the total count of votes up & down**, in your Show action, you could do something like this:

```
#in controller
def show
  @microphoto = Microphoto.find(params[:id])
end

#in view
Total of votes up: <%= @microphoto.votes_up %>
Total of votes down: <%= @microphoto.votes_down %>
<%= link_to "vote up", vote_up_microphotos_url(feed_item.id), :method => :put %> 
<%= link_to "vote down", vote_down_microphotos_url(feed_item.id), :method => :put %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. would you please let me know how could I render the result number of votes_up and votes_down, in my view?I am a newbie

Comment: @Arash I just updated my answer, let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: $MrYoshiji I think there is problem with '<%= @microphoto.votes_up %>' as it does not render anything on page

Comment: Try using `<%= @microphoto.votes_up || "NIL" %>` if it displays "NIL" instead of the count, it means the attribute votes_up is nil.

Comment: Another problem, must be a typo, but I dont find it. votes_up link works and renders correctly but votes_down not! `uninitialized constant MicrophotosController::O`

Comment: would you please answer question in my last comment ?

Comment: This is a "o" (not zero, the alphabetical o, not 0)

Comment: This problem was because I typed a "o" (letter) instead of a Zero, probably a lack of concentration at this moment, sorry for that @Arash

Answer (score 0):

If you just set the values of `votes_up` and `votes_down` on the initialize method to 0, your code should work. You may need to update your database with default values as well.